# How to add class in a div if the year is current year in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have my div like the following...

```
<div class="slider-slide-wrap current_year shown slide{{yr}}" ng-repeat="yr in yeardata"></div>
```

in {{yr}} I am getting stored year data.Here I need to check the condition If {{yr}} == {{currentyear}} then I need to add the classes 'shown' and 'current_year ' to the div .

How is this possible??

Comment: try using ng-class="{yr == currentYear : sampleClass}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use directive **ng-class**

```
<div **ng-class={'shown current_year': yr == currentyear, }** class="slider-slide-wrap current_year shown slide{{yr}}" ng-repeat="yr in yeardata"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-class` (link to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

You can set a class based on a condition with it, using it like this:

`<div ng-class={ 'your-class': year === currentYear }></div>`

The ng-class argument is a dictionary, so you can set multiple classes with it (like you wanted to), using it like:

`<div ng-class={ 'your-class': year === currentYear, 'your-second-class': year === currentYear }></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-class`

```
ng-class="{'clasName':yr==currentyear}"
```